# Safely exec tmux upon login

Tags: shell, exec, tmux, fish

I would like to execute `tmux` upon logging into a shell for my user. I am using `fish`, but I think this question is relevant to any shell. So far, I've accomplished this by following the advice in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/560253/automatically-running-tmux-in-fish, specifically, adding the following line to my `config.fish`:

```
test $TERM != "screen"; and exec tmux
```

However, I have one major issue with this approach, and that is if `tmux` fails to start, perhaps if I've introduced a syntax error in my `.tmux.conf` file, the shell process immediately exits, booting me out of the session.

Is there a way to automatically run tmux in new shell executions whereby I can:

- Catch errors and fallback on a "plain" shell execution (i.e. just `fish` without `tmux`)
- Not have to exit a login twice - once to quit `tmux` then again to quit `fish`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
if status --is-login
    source $HOME/.config/fish/login.fish
    tmux; and exec true
end
```

Obviously you may or may not have a login.fish file. I like to keep my config.fish lean by putting code that might not be needed for the current session in separate files so I've also got a interactive.fish script

Comment: `tmux; and exec true` seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks! Another virtual +1 (stackoverflow newbies can't) for the separate fish files tip.

Comment: relevant `fish` issue regarding `exec true` vs. `exit`: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/991

Answer (score 2):

I imagine tmux exits with a non-zero (i.e. failing) status if there's configuration errors, so you could presumably ditch the exec and exit manually, like

```
if test $TERM != "screen"
    tmux
    and exit
end
```

However, do keep in mind that fish *always* sources all of its config files, so you'll want to wrap this inside `if status --is-login` or similar.

Comment: I'd +1 this if I was allowed, being a stackoverflow newbie and all, because of the excellent `if status --is-login` tip, but this solution still causes me to have to exit the shell twice. I'm not sure why.

Comment: It seems `tmux`, being a client-server program, exits immediately with status `1`, even though the `tmux` session continues.

Comment: No, I just forgot another piece of fish: "If exit is called while sourcing a file (using the source builtin) the rest of the file will be skipped, but the shell itself will not exit." (from [the docs](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#exit)